# Disconnect socket when browser is in background

Tags: node.js, sockets, background, background-foreground

I am using Mobile and Desktop Browsers, When web page opens a socket connection will be established with server. Working fine the browser is in foregroud.

But, when user minimizes the Browser then still that socket is still connected.

What I want is Disconnect socket when Browser goes to background, Just disconnect socket and connect socket back when browser comes back to foreground.

Thanksfor your help!

Comment: What about:

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {

    // close websocket connection here.. 
}, false);

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) how to cache the event when the window is not active anymore. In the event handler just call the api which close your socket connection.

Hope it helps.